# Building WP7 in TeamCity

Tags: windows-phone-7, teamcity, msbuild-4.0

I have been working to try and get my WP7 application building in Teamcity. To do this, I have managed to get the dlls and .target files requires for the application to build successfully.

The problem I am having is when it comes to the Xap Packaging. The Xap Packaging step happens as follows:

```
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] XapPackager
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Begin Xap packaging
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Creating file MyApp.xap
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding WMAppManifest.xml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Background.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding ApplicationIcon.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Caliburn.Micro.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Caliburn.Micro.Extensions.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Hammock.WindowsPhone.Mango.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.WindowsPhone.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Newtonsoft.Json.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Telerik.Windows.Core.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding TombstoneHelper.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding YourLastAboutDialog.dll
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Content\About\Data.xml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.check.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.delete.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.feature.email.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.feature.settings.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.refresh.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Iconography\appbar.save.rest.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\fail.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\Icon_External_Link.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\lock.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\success.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\Thumbs\fail.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\Thumbs\success.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\Thumbs\unknown.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Resources\Images\unknown.png
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding SplashScreenImage.jpg
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding SubmissionInfo\ManualTestResults.xml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding SubmissionInfo\Settings.xml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding Content\About\AboutStyles.xaml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding AppManifest.xaml
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] Adding SplashScreenImage.jpg
[16:18:03]: [XapPackager] (1, 1): Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

The last line where it talks about the xap Packaging failing is not hugely descriptive. There are no locks on the xap file

Using Visual Studio locally, that last line should look as follows:

```
Xap packaging completed successfully
```

This is frustrating - has anyone seen something similar? I am using a simple MSbuild 4.0 runner in Teamcity

Thanks

Paul

Comment: It could be that you are not having all files required on the buildserver. Are you referencing something that is not included in the build? The easiest way to find out is to either open the solution on the builderver (if you have VS installed there) or try to compare the files.

Comment: @Jon all files are in place. The build is successful but its the XapPackaging part of the task (post build) that fails. I have found that it is in the Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.dll of the WP7 SDK